# How do I allocate GCHandle to structure when structure contains bool

Tags: c#, pointers, pinvoke

I have been trying to create a handle to a structure type because I need a pinned pointer to it, but I am getting the error "Object contains non-primitive or non-blittable data"

My structure looks like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct MyStruct
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
    public bool Test;
}
```

Now, when I call,

```
var mystruct = new MyStruct();
var handle = GCHandle.Alloc(mystruct, GCHandleType.Pinned);
```

I get the error "Object contains non-primitive or non-blittable data". Now I understand that the bool field is a non-blittable type. But I was under the impression that by adding the MarshalAs attribute, I could tell the marshaller how to convert the type. (I also tried `UnmanagedType.Bool`)

This structure has to be defined globally, because it is needed throughout my class. The only reason I need the pointer is because I have an unmanaged API that must pass this structure as a pointer. Then I have to get that structure in a callback and read/update members.

So this is the basic scenario.

1. Structure is created globally in a managed class
2. Pointer to structure is obtained
3. Pointer to the structure is passed into the API
4. The API calls a static method callback where I then need to get my structure and read/update members.

I tried to use `Marshal.StructureToPtr` but this only creates a copy, so if in my managed class I update the member, when the callback is raised, the updated value is not there.

Does anyone know how I can get a pinned pointer to my structure so I can read/modify the public members and have them available in the callback?

Thanks

Comment: here is the list of blittable types http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75dwhxf7.aspx

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You've got more than one problem here.  Using a *struct* is highly inadvisable.  It will get boxed before the GCHandle.Alloc() call and *that* boxed object gets pinned.  You cannot see any updates to it through your *mystruct* variable.  Use a *class* instead.

And avoid *bool*, it is a non-blittable type due to its highly variable implementation.  It is 4 bytes in C, 1 byte in C++, 2 bytes in COM.  Just make it a *byte* instead.  You can write a property to get it back to a bool.

So:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class MyStruct
{
    private byte _test;
    public bool Test {
       get { return _test != 0; }
       set { _test = value ? 1 : 0; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I did indeed try it as a class as well, but I was hung up on trying to force it to use a bool type. I read the answer by @hvd, and he is right. It looks like MarshalAs just does not do anything there. I had tried it as an int just to see if I could create a `GCHandle`, and I could, but I didn't like the idea of it. I'm marking this one as answer, because I had not considered using a property to wrap the member. I will give this a try! Thanks!

Comment: ECMA-335 11.7.4 says "Boolean. 4-byte integer value where any nonzero
value represents TRUE, and 0 represents
FALSE." That does not sound highly variable to me. I am going to assume it was an oversight or perhaps was decided because the semantics are different than regular integer types and not a technical decision.

Answer (score 7):

You're right that you're telling the marshaller how to marshal the type.

But that won't do you any good when you then attempt to bypass the marshaller.

You need to decide whether you want to use the marshaller, or whether you want the unmanaged code to directly write into managed memory.

If you want to use the marshaller:

Generally, a good way to handle this is to use it in both directions. You can use `Marshal.StructureToPtr` (as you've found), call the external function, and then use `Marshal.PtrToStructure` to convert it back into your managed representation.

Or you can use methods that are set up in such a way that marshalling happens automatically, without you needing to specify this manually. For example, calling a native method taking a `ref MyStruct` parameter will allow for that to happen.

If you don't want to use the marshaller:

Don't use any types that require marshalling. As Hans Passant comments, use a different type instead, `byte` would probably be a good choice.

(I'll refrain from commenting on the advantages and disadvantages of using structs here, except that the points already made about it are well worth reading and understanding.)